# page appears in global search result but not local!

Tags: seo, search-results

I live in Iran and usualy use "Anti Filter" programs like "freegate" for accessing web.

when I use "freegate" and search google for "example keyword" that relates to one of my website pages, my website page appears in SERP.

but when I dont use "freegate", my page disappear from search results!

I check for penalty but my website is ok and not penalized.

thanks for help.

Comment: Can you find your page(s) by doing a `site:` search, eg. `site:example.com example keywords`?

Comment: @w3d yes. my page is in first result when I search with your suggested way. have you any idea?